# How can I paste the content copied to my clipboard in my tcl script to the Linux terminal

Tags: linux, tcl, clipboard, tclsh

I use the below commands to copy string "xyz" to clipboard in my tcl script. But I am not able to paste the same content on the linux terminal. How can I paste the Content copied to my clipboard in the script to the Linux terminal.

```
clipboard clear
clipboard append "xyz"
```

Comment: There are many linux terminals. Which are you running?

Comment: I'm using etx. I have a table widget. I retrieve the table row and copy one perticular cell value to the clipboard